# Visual Studio 2013: Error MSB4014: The build was aborted because of an internal failure

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2013, compiler-errors

After using VS08 without any problem for several months, I've decided to install VS2013. Unfortunately, VS won't stop crashing after Building/Rebuilding/Cleaning a simple project.

I have just created an empty project with a main.cpp file outputing "Test", but it keep posting this error.

- I have seen some posts about it on VS08 and a Microsoft hotfix for it but nothing on VS2013, and nothing that solved my problem.
- I've tried uninstalling/reinstalling VS2013

What would cause this issue?

[image]

Comment: If your project is so short, why not give us your code?

Comment: Check this link: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CSIVisualStudioUnableToTranslateUnicodeCharacterAtIndexXToSpecifiedCodePage.aspx

Comment: @Aracthor No matter what project it is, I'll still get this error. Plus this isn't an error related to code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Hanselman's blog](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CSIVisualStudioUnableToTranslateUnicodeCharacterAtIndexXToSpecifiedCodePage.aspx), this error might be caused by an invalid character in your PATH variable. BuildParameters, included in your error log, is only called when reading the environment variables, so it seems that your PATH variable got corrupted somehow.

Comment: Oh my. It's nice of Visual Studio to detect, but decidedly un-nice to crash.

Comment: @Jaco Thank you for this link, I'll check this out ASAP. Weird thing though is that I didn't get this error with any other VS used until now... I guess it might be something new with 2013... I'll keep you in touch

Comment: @Jaco That was it ! I had a chinese character right in my path variable ! Thank you so much !!